# Python Iterating through nested list using list comprehension

Tags: python, arrays, list-comprehension

I'm working on Euler Project, problem 11, which involves finding the greatest product of all possible combinations of four adjacent numbers in a grid.  I've split the numbers into a nested list and used a list comprehension to slice the relevant numbers, like this:

```
if x+4 <= len(matrix[x]): #check right
    my_slice = [int(matrix[x][n]) for n in range(y,y+4)]
```

...and so on for the other cardinal directions.  So far, so good.  But when I get to the diagonals things get problematic.  I tried to use two ranges like this:

```
if x+4 <= len(matrix[x]) and y-4 >=0:# check up, right
    my_slice = [int(matrix[m][n]) for m,n in ((range(x,x+4)),range(y,y+4))]
```

But this yields the following error:

```
<ipython-input-53-e7c3ebf29401> in <listcomp>(.0)
 48     if x+4 <= len(matrix[x]) and y-4 >=0:# check up, right
---> 49         my_slice = [int(matrix[m][n]) for m,n in ((range(x,x+4)),range(y,y+4))]
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

My desired indices for x,y values of `[0,0]` would be `['0,0','1,1','2,2','3,3']`. This does not seem all that different for using the enumerate function to iterate over a list, but clearly I'm missing something.

P.S.  My apologies for my terrible variable nomenclature, I'm a work in progress.

Comment: Try zipping the ranges?

Comment: Are you working with *arrays* or *lists*? They are not the same thing.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, it is a nested list, in fact. Edited to reflect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use two ranges, simply use one and apply it twice:

```
my_slice = [int(matrix[m][m-x+y]) for m in range(x,x+4)]
```

Since your `n` is supposed to be *attached* to `range(y,y+4)` we know that there will always be a difference of `y-x` between `m` and `n`. So instead of using two variables, we can counter the difference ourselves.

Or in case you still wish to use two `range(..)` constructs, you can use `zip(..)` which takes a list of generators, consumes them concurrently and emits tuples:

```
my_slice = [int(matrix[m][n]) for m,n in zip(range(x,x+4),range(y,y+4))]
```

But I think this will not improve performance because of the tuple packing and unpacking overhead.

Comment: /facepalm for not realizing the x and y ranges are always the same.  I'm not too worried about performance since this is just for learning purposes.   Thanks, accepted!

Answer (score 0):

`[int(matrix[x+d][n+d]) for d in range(4)]` for one diagonal.
`[int(matrix[x+d][n-d]) for d in range(4)]` for the other.

Btw, better use standard matrix index names, i.e., row `i` and column `j`. Not `x` and `y`. It's confusing. I think you even confused yourself, as for example your `if x+4 <= len(matrix[x])` tests `x` against the second dimension length but uses it in the first dimension. Huh?

Comment: It wouldn't be the first time I confused myself, thanks for the constructive criticism.  I struggle with variable/index naming.